# Pop up alert What the user have written in a textbox

Tags: javascript, html, popup, alert

I have an exercise for my University and i'm stuck. I want to make a page which by pressing the "Search" button will display a pop-up (alert) with the content of the textbox containing the "Student Id" , while pressing the "Insert" button will display a pop-up (alert) with the contents of the textbox containing "First Name".

Here is my code :

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="/action_page.php">
<label for="studentid">Student Id:</laber><br>
<input type="text" id="studentid" name="studentid"><br>
<label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
<label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
<button type="button">Search</button>
<button type="button">Insert</button> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, could you add what you've tried until now instead of only the form code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far. This is a college exercise which is considered a homework question, and the [guidelines for homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) are that we can help you get to the answer, not to give you the code. Please show us your attempt to do this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your HTML to include this on the buttons:

```html
<button type="button" onclick="search()">Search</button>
<button type="button" onclick="insert()">Insert</button>
```

and add this to the end:

```html
<script>
function search() {
    let studentID = document.querySelector("#studentid").value;
    alert(studentID);
}
function insert() {
    let firstName = document.querySelector("#fname").value;
    alert(firstName);
}
</script>
```

This HTML code will run the javascript functions "`search()`" or "`insert()`" on click respectively, which do the following:

1. Create a variable, and assign the value of either the "`studentid`" or "`fname`" elements to it.
2. Alert() the contents of the variable.

The `onclick` attribute runs javascript assigned to it when the element it is on is clicked.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) for guidelines on how to answer homework questions and college assignments. The guidelines are that we can help guide the user to the answer, not to give you the code.